# python - JSON data to CSV - Loop through all JSON data and export to CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, export-to-csv

I am trying to export all JSON data(below) held in the response2 variable to a CSV file. When i run the full code, it only exports the first item from the response2 variable. The CSV headers work perfectly but not all the rows are populated, only the first one is exported to the CSV.
how do i loop through and export all the keys and values to CSV?

Sorry, i'm still learning python, please help

```
[{'device_name': 'fk6sdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b1bvf6e17ee11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935830f3a9df8e9b6425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toh122soft\\thcasdf3\\toho34rce.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user1']}, {'device_name': 'fk6sdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b151f6e17ee11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['bfc7dcf5935f3a9df8e9b6830425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518fc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f712f6dd4641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\oft\\tf3\\tootsice.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user2']}, {'device_name': '6asdsdc2', 'device_timestamp': '2020-10-27T00:50:46.176Z', 'event_id': '9b151f698e11eb81b', 'process_effective_reputation': 'LIST', 'process_hash': ['9df8ebfc7dcf5935830f3a9b6425c37a', 'ca9f3a24506cc518ff6ddc939a33c100b2d557f96e040f7124641ad1734e2f19'], 'process_name': 'c:\\program files (x86)\\toht\\th3\\tohce.exe', 'process_username': ['JOHN\\user3']}]

r = requests.get(hostname + url_results + searchjobid + "/results", headers=headers)
res = json.loads(r.text) 
response2 = response["results"]


csv_writer = csv.writer(open('events.csv', 'w', newline=''))

csv_writer.writerow(["device_name", "device_timestamp", "event_id", "process_effective_reputation",
                     "process_hash", "process_name", "process_username"])

for evs in response2:
    csv_writer.writerow([evs["device_name"],
                         evs["device_timestamp"],
                         evs["event_id"],
                         evs["process_effective_reputation"],
                         evs["process_hash"],
                         evs["process_name"],
                         evs["process_username"]])
```

Thank you

Comment: I recommend removing the `requests` part from the question, and confirming that the issue happens with the fixed dict that is shown at the top.

Comment: Seems to be writing all 3 lines to me: https://repl.it/repls/AjarPricklyRuntime

Comment: thanks njzk2, for some reason i changed nothing, just restarted pycharm..weird thank for checking out though